# tracker-thunderbird-plugin does not work

Tags: fedora, gnome, thunderbird

I installed *tracker-thunderbird-plugin* in order to have my emails indexed by tracker and integrated into Gnome search.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Typing in any search string into Gnome's search field does not return any result from Thunderbird.

Does anyone know how to debug? Or, how to make it happen?

My system is Fedora 22 with Gnome 3.16 (but the plugin was also not working using Fedora 21 with Gnome 3.14). Version/release of tracker-plugin is 1.4.2-1.fc22.x86_64. Thunderbird is release 38.5.0.

In general, *tracker* is functional on my system.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have the plugin enabled? Can you try it with SELinux  **temporary** in permissive mode?

Comment: So, I did a `setenforce permissive` and restarted the tracker process, which kept my CPU and disk pretty busy for a while but didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: How to enable the plugin?